# following sibling xpath not working in my code

Tags: html, selenium, xpath

```
<html>
    <title> COSTOMER LOGIN </title>
    <body>
        <h1>FLIPKART</h1>
        <div class="ft">
            <img src="glass.jpg" height="80" width="80"/>
            <input type="button" value="100RS"/>
        </div>
        <div class="ft">
            <img src="glass.png" height="80" width="80"/>
            <input type="button" value="100RS"/>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

following sibling not working:

```
//img[@src='glass.png']]/following-sibling::button[@type='button']
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a `button` tag you are looking for, but `input`:

```
//img[@src='glass.png']]/following-sibling::input[@type='button']
```